# Проблема с вводом чисел с десятичной запятой в приложении Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

В приложении Xamarin.Forms под Android необходимо вводить и отображать числа с одним знаком после запятой.

```
    <Entry Text="{Binding Path=FlourWeight, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:F1}'}" 
WidthRequest="90" Keyboard="Numeric" Completed="Entry_Completed"/>
```

Проблема в том, что при помещении курсора в это поле и попытке ввода любой цифры поле заполняется большим количеством нулей до запятой и корректный ввод в это поле невозможен. К полю привязано свойство типа double. Подскажите, как корректно реализовать ввод чисел с десятичной запятой в приложении Xamarin.Forms

```
public class Recipe : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Поля
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private double flourWeight;
    private double humidity;

    // Свойства
    public int Id                                   
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); }
    }         
    public string Name                             
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }                
    public double FlourWeight                      
    {
        get { return flourWeight; }
        set { flourWeight = value; OnPropertyChanged("FlourWeight"); }
    }         
    public double Humidity                        
    {
        get { return humidity; }
        set { humidity = value; OnPropertyChanged("Humidity"); }
    }            


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

И конструктор страницы:

```
public partial class AddRecipePage : ContentPage
{

    private Recipe SelectedRecipe;  
    private bool IsNewRecipe;

    public AddRecipePage(Recipe recipe, bool isNewRecipe)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SelectedRecipe = recipe;
        IsNewRecipe = isNewRecipe;

        this.BindingContext = SelectedRecipe;
    }
}
```

При вводе например цифры 5 вот такое сообщение в логе:
[0:] Binding: 50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0 can not be converted to type 'System.Double'

Отключил проверки текста: IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: возможно, описание вашей проблемы будет более понятным, если вы добавите к тексту вопроса код метода `Entry_Completed` и связанного `FlourWeight`.

Comment: В методе Entry_Completed пересчитываются значения других свойств. Метод никак не влияет на проблему, так как проблема возникает до вызова этого метода при попытке ввода любой цифры в поле. Связанное сейчас добавлю

Comment: В общем проблема возникает при установке Mode=TwoWay и использовании формата строки числа с десятичными знаками. Похоже, это ошибка в Xamarin.Forms. Пока единственное решение - установить Mode=OneWay и вручную сохранять введенное число в привязанное свойство типа double

Answer (score 0):

может уже поздно отвечать, но всё же. скорее всего надо
StringFormat='{}{0:F1}'
заменить на
StringFormat='0:#.##'

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings